# Lyrics of The Lettermen's Put away your teardrops

Tags: lyrics

I really do like this old song:
The Lettermen' *Put away your teardrops*

I'd like to have the lyrics. I have searched the lyrics on the internet, but there is nothing. So I typed the lyrics by myself. **Could anyone help me check it?**

Every time you think about him
It only hurts you more
You're much better up without him
So get smart and teach your heart to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line of the second verse, the word should be `off` rather than `up`.